# Binomial sum of derivatives

Tags: derivatives, binomial-coefficients, summation

I would like to know the result of the following sum:

$$\sum_{p=0}^m \binom{m}{p}(-1)^{p-1}\frac{\partial^{p-1}}{\partial x^{p-1}}f(x)\cdot(-1)^{m-p-1}\frac{\partial^{m-p-1}}{\partial x^{m-p-1}}g(x)$$

with $$\frac{\partial^{-1}}{\partial x^{-1}}=\int dx$$

Thanks

Comment: For $p=0$ or $p=m$, what is $\frac{\partial^{-1}}{\partial x^{-1}}$? Antiderivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull out the factors of $-1$ to yield an overall factor $(-1)^m$. Also it's unclear why you're using partial derivatives, as there's only one variable; I'll use total derivatives. Then

\begin{align}
&
\sum_{p=0}^m\binom mp\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^{p-1}f(x)\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^{m-p-1}g(x)
\\
=&
\sum_{p=0}^m\binom mp\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^p\int f(x)\mathrm dx\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^{m-p}\int g(x)\mathrm dx
\\
=&
\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^m\left(\int f(x)\mathrm dx\int g(x)\mathrm dx\right)\;.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. And what about summing over all $m$s? I mean $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{2m+1}}{m!\Gamma(m+2)}\quad \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^m\left(\int f(x)\mathrm dx\int g(x)\mathrm dx\right)$$

Comment: @JFNJr: You can write that formally as a [Bessel function of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind_:_J.CE.B1); but you'd need to use the square root of the differential operator; I don't know whether that's of any use to you.

Comment: What's the meaning of 'the square root of the differential operator'?

Comment: @JFNJr: You can read about that at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html) (see also [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semiderivative.html)); but as I said, this is just a formal manipulation that you need in order to write this as a Bessel function; I have no idea whether it's meaningful in your case.